# Creating a chrono-node customer parsing with a relative date

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using the https://github.com/wanasit/chrono package and was trying to expand the functionality to include an additional abbreviation. ('m' for minutes)

You'll notice `m => minutes` does not exist in the mapping array found here: https://github.com/wanasit/chrono/blob/1320d7c403cb4da23a8e06d82fcff5748f552936/src/locales/en/constants.ts#L136

I tried using a custom parser but I'm not quite understanding how it works:

```
const custom = chrono.casual.clone();
custom.parsers.push({
    pattern: () => {
        return /([\b|0-9]+)(m)\b/i;
    },
    extract: (context, match) => {
        return {
            minute: match[1]
        };
    }
});
```

If I type "in 15mins" (native parsing) it adds 15 minutes to "now" (relative)
If I type "in 5m" using my customer parser, it sets the times minute to 5. (absolute)

How do I make my parser work with times relative to "now"

Comment: This could get very complicated since you'd be doing natural language processing?

Comment: I think the library handles most of the difficulty. I think I just need to figure out how to return a 'relative' date vs an absolute date.